# batch file to Arranging text file on a certain pattern

Tags: batch-file, tidy

I want batch file to Arranging text file on a certain pattern

Notice:There are things will not change in each line will start

```
1:

2:

3:

4:

5:
```

but sometimes the Arrangement be untidy like

```
1:

3:

2:

5:

4:
```

i want batch file to change the Arrangement from untidy to the normal tidy (1: 2: 3: 4: 5:)

((i want the batch file to support changing all arrangement to be tidy not this examples only))

Comment: Are you asking how to rearrange the lines of a text file in sorted order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this on your text files: if it doesn't solve your problem then explain further by editing your question.

```
sort <"file.txt"  >"newfile.txt"
```